# Use WDAC to block an EXE except when called by specific program? Possible?

Tags: windows, windows-defender, security-policy, whitelist

**Context:** When Windows Defender Application Control blocks a program, in the Event Viewer log it also shows which application/process tried to open the blocked exe. For example it says this, followed by the file that was blocked (I truncated the message):  `Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume7\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) attempted to load....`

**Question:** Since Windows already keeps track of the program that attempted to run the file, is it possible to allow *only* specific processes/files to run a specified application?

What got me thinking was Microsoft has [a list of programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/design/applications-that-can-bypass-wdac) that it recommends be blocked because they can be used to bypass WDAC and AppLocker. But some of these might be required for certain users, so it does say "Unless your use scenarios explicitly require them". But being able to only allow specific processes to use it would be better than just allowing it outright.

Comment: Looks like you can use "per-app" rules to allow a file to be executed by a specific application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/design/use-wdac-policy-to-control-specific-plug-ins-add-ins-and-modules though I'm not sure whether this applies when something spins off a separate process